# Rails Model not taking configuration value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I've created a custom configuration parameter, but somehow my User model is not able to access its value.

In `configuration.rb`:

```
config.x.user.starting_cash = 50
```

In my User model:

```
  # Create wallet for each new user
  after_create :create_wallet

  # Block for creating a new wallet for each new user
  def create_wallet
    @wallet = Wallet.new(user_id: self.id, cash: Rails.configuration.x.user.starting_cash)
    @wallet.save
  end
```

It does create a wallet for a new user, but the value of `cash` is empty instead of `50`. When is manually set cash to an int of 50, it works just fine:

```
@wallet = Wallet.new(user_id: self.id, cash: 50)
```

When I access the configuration parameter in the Rails console, it works as expected:

```
2.6.3 :022 > Rails.configuration.x.user.starting_cash
 => 50
```

Documentation I have searched in for solutions, includes: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#custom-configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I had to restart the (development) server for the configuration parameter to load. Didn't know that.

Guess it's a beginner mistake, but I do feel that the Rails documentation could be a bit more explicit about this since we don't have to restart the server for changes to e.g. controllers.

Comment: Good job! I was wondering what was going wrong. Yes, anything touches to the config need to restart the rails server to take effect.

Comment: Rails only reloads constants that are loaded by the autoloader. In your average Rails app this only means classes in `/app`. Most things configuration related require a restart. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html